# How to use Python to extract packet information from hexdump?

Tags: python, scapy, pcap, hexdump, wireshark-dissector

I am working on a network project where I have hexdump of packets and I need to dissect that hexdump packet to display all the packet information.

Example : Packet Information Fields -

```
source address
destination address
encapsulation type
frame number
frame length
FCS
data
epoch time
```

We are not supposed to use file as input and output because it will increase memory utilization and might crash server.

I tried with below code but this doesn't work in my case:

```
# imports scapy Utility

from scapy.all import *
from scapy.utils import *

# variable to store hexdump

hexdump = '0000  49 47 87 95 4a 30 9e 9c f7 09 70 7f....'

# Initialize a 802.11 structure from raw bytes

packet = Dot11(bytearray.fromhex(hexdump))

#scapy function to view the info

packet.summary()
packet.show()
```

Are there any suggestions to achieve this as I am new to this technology? I might lack some proper directions to solve this.

Comment: What do you mean with _display all the packet information_? Split the header/body? Convert it to ascii strings? The question isn't entirely clear imo.

Comment: @ChukUltima I have added more information on packet Information fields , please check my edited description.

Answer (score 2):

Your `hexdump` value seem to include the index. Remove it:

- On Scapy >= 2.4rc:

  ```
  data = hex_bytes('49 47 87 95 4a 30 9e 9c f7 09 70 7f [...]'.replace(' ', ''))
  ```
- Or with Python 2 and Scapy <= 2.3.3:

  ```
  data = '49 47 87 95 4a 30 9e 9c f7 09 70 7f [...]'.replace(' ', '').decode('hex')
  ```

Then:

```
Dot11(data)
```